# Django not installing

Tags: django

I am trying to instal Django on my new mac. I am not able to do so. Please advice. I also tried sudo commmands, but this only installs with python 2 and not 3

[image: Termanal Example with error]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to separate the `==` from the name of the package and the version: `pip3 install django==3.0.3`